# Django serving stale form validation choices

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, caching

I have a series of views that builds a set of associations and then triggers an action based on that association.

For validation, I've built a custom function in forms.py and use that to populate the initial choices/validation values.

```
def targets():
    o = []
    for r in Target.objects.all():
        o.append((r.pk, r.host.statline()))
    return o

class StageForm(forms.Form):
    targets = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=targets(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

In the view, I calculate a new list pertinent to the Build Object, checking to make sure all the required parameters have been defined, and submit that as the presented choices.

```
hl = Target.objects.filter(build=b)
   cl = []
   for h in hl:
       if h.host.ready():
          cl.append((h.pk, h.host.statline()))
       form.fields['targets'].choices = cl
```

The problem I'm seeing is that if I add a new host to the environment, the form operates as I expect and presents the hosts ready for a build, but then the presented option fails validation.

The list I generate from the build and the list I generate for validation is coming from the same place, and the new host is clearly in the table, but it doesn't present to the validation until I restart the development server.

To add to the strangeness, I get the expected results from the `manage.py shell` while the form is still validating with stale data.

Is this just because I'm running on the development server, or is my methodology here just untenable and should be switched to overriding the `__init__` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with a queryset.

```
class StageForm(forms.Form):
    targets = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Target.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

(If the Target string representation does not output the correct display value, you can subclass the field and define `label_from_formset`, as shown in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).